# framebuffer size

Tags: graphics

Does the framebuffer contain depth buffer information, or just color buffer information in graphics applications? What about for gui's on windows, is their a frame buffer and does it hold both color buffer + depth info or just color info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for real-time 3D, the "standard" buffers are the color buffer, in RGBA format, 1 byte per component, and the depth buffer, 3 bytes per component. There is one sample per fragment ( i.e., if you have 8x antialiasing, you will have 8 colors and 8 depth samples per pixel )

Now, many applications use additional, custom buffers. They are usually called g-buffers. These can include : object ID, material ID, albedo, shininess, normals, tangent, binormal, AO factor, most influent lights impacting the fragment, etc. At 1080p and 4xMSAA and double- or triple-buffering, this can take huge amounts of memory, so all these information are usually packed as tightly as possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about the kernel-level framebuffer in Linux, it sets both the resolution and the color depth. Here's a list of [common framebuffer modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions#Other_commonly_available_modes); notice that the modes are determined by both the resolution and the color depth. You can override the framebuffer by passing a command line parameter to the kernel in your bootloader (`vga=...`).

Unlike Linux, on Windows the graphics subsystem is a part of the OS. I don't *think* (and, please, someone correct me if I'm wrong) there is support for non-VGA output devices in the latest Windows, so the framebuffer is deprecated/unavailable there.

Comment: I presume the original poster is asking about depth information as in a z-buffer for 3d applications rather than color depth. I might be wrong though.

Comment: @John I wasn't (and still am not) sure. The only tag for the q is `graphics`, which isn't saying much.

Comment: I think the question needs some additional clarification.